# http streaming TO server FROM client (mobile device)

Tags: client-server, http-streaming

I know it's possible to stream content from a server to a web browser. I'm curious if there is a method to allow the same in reverse; and once a page is requested/connection established to then try and keep it open and stream content to the server from the client without continually re-initiating a connection/POSTing to the server. I have tried searching for such a thing but I always find information about http streaming from server to client and not the other way around. This is specifically to target mobile devices and stream chunks of text up to the server.

Thanks in advance for any info or advice!

Comment: Is websocket what you're looking for? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: I don't want to use sockets, I stream from the server like this: http://bottlepy.org/docs/0.11/async.html#greenlets-to-the-rescue